# Is the following C++ code thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parameters

Is the following

```
int BlkArray::GetNthBlockA(unsigned int n, const Block *&pfb, int &maxIndex) const {
    if (n + 1 >= (unsigned int)formattingPivots.GetCount()) return -1;
    pfb = formattingPivots.GetNthBlckB(n);
    maxIndex = formattingPivots.GetNthInt(n + 1) - 1;
    return formattingPivots.GetNthInt(n);
}
```

thread safe considering:

1. `formattingPivots.GetNthBlckB(n)`, `formattingPivots.GetNthInt(n + 1)`, `formattingPivots.GetNthInt(n)` and `formattingPivots.GetCount()` are all `const` methods.
2. I call GetNthBlock() from 2 threads, when thread1 calls and returns an usual Block I notice a side effect in thread2.
3. const Block *&pfb is passed as follows from each thread's worker method:

   ```
   int maxIndex;
   const Block *pfb = null;
   pStoredBlcks->GetNthBlockA(blockBreakIndex, pfb, maxIndex);
   ```

I'm concerned `const` might be causing an unintended effect in persisting between both workers' bodies. I'm 98% the bugs I get are from the code above but, being peculiar to multithreading I can't get much more sure.

I'm getting near my question limit for 24 hrs, on one more thing, if it might help. Is `static_cast<>` thread safe? (Silly? yeah but I wrote C for years) I ask because of:

```
const Block *GetNthblckB(int n) const {
    return static_cast<const Block*>(Blocks.GetAt(n));//Returns `Object`* without cast.
}
```

3am_*_*_
Thanks for the encouragement guys. I just surrounded that call with a CritSecMonitor and I still have the side effect. Short of reading the valgrind manual I better catch some zz's.

Comment: `static_cast` doesn't do anything at runtime when used on pointers so you can use it without fear of messing up threads. Also you can use critical sections to see if your problem is coming from multiple threads running that code at the same time.

Comment: @SethCarnegie unless he is casting away the fact that the method's implementation is changing state - in that case, a mutex may be needed

Comment: @SethCarnegie, I am using `Monitor`s (CS). But I have drilled deeply into non-critical sections to target this bug. I don't mind them running the code at the same time, even if they share the `pStoredBlcks` (they do) they should be safe in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to my question, I thought someone else had already said this:

Don't assume any library function is thread safe unless it says it is.

My 98% guess was wrong and the thread unsafe method lay elsewhere in a library instance method using completely seperate objects but being called from two threads. There must have been a static variable in there somewhere as the call stacks where it would crash (very rarely) looked to be deep inside library code.

Answer (score 3):

**The #1 fact of thread safety:**  If two functions `f()` and `g()` are both thread safe, then the following function is not necessarily thread safe:

```
// h might not be thread-safe!
void h()
{
    f(); // f is thread-safe
    g(); // g is thread-safe
}
```

So you will have to prove thread-safety based on the contents of the functions `GetNthBlckB`, `GetNthInt`, etc.  I don't know what these methods do, so I don't know if they are thread-safe or not (`const` has nothing to do with it).  It *looks* like it is not thread-safe to me.

Comment: They do very little but call library methods. I don't know if those library methods are thread safe, they claim to emulate an array. `Osp::Base::Collection::ArrayList`. http://developer.bada.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.osp.cppapireference.help/classOsp_1_1Base_1_1Collection_1_1ArrayList.html `int GetNthInt(int n) const {
 int reti;
 GetAt(n, reti);
 return reti;
}`

Comment: @John: The definition of "thread-safe" that appears in library documentation varies from library to library.  Does the library say that concurrent access to the same object is allowed?  Many libraries use the definition that "thread safe" means "safe as long as two threads don't use the same object".  Other libraries allow multiple concurrent reads but require exclusion for changes.

Answer (score 0):

Is Blocks.GetAt() an immutable method (doesn't change any internal state)?  It may not be, if it is using a cache to read from a database or from a file, for instance.

Also, the answer to your question would also depend on when the data was initialized.

Is it before any threads are spawned?

Also, I recommend that you using valgrind's [drd](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/drd-manual.html) and [helgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html) regularly on your project to help you find current bugs as well as preventing future threading bugs from getting into your project.

#### Last Recommendation

One last suggestion, when in doubt about thread-safety, put in your own mutex.
If you can show that it runs fine **with the mutex** then you can isolate the bug/false assumptions/critical section(s).

Comment: Initialization comes well before I let the threads off. GetAt() is an immutable method.

Comment: Then I recommend you pull up valgrind's drd (added links in the answer).

Comment: Will it be any use if I don't whether the library methods for array access are thread safe? I suspect I'd have to prove that for myself.

Comment: You should be able to convince yourself by using a combination of a mutex and a thread-checker.

Comment: I was kinda hoping to avoid passing a CSMonitor this deep into what should be thread safe non-critical sections.